# Why I can't use runOnUiThread() to update an adapter?

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, runnable

I have an adapter and a spinner view which is set to use the adapter for it's entries. I'm adding items to adapter from a list of all files in /assets/ folder, I found that this task takes very long time (even about 2 seconds for a list of 2 files on a 1.5Ghz phone!). Then I came up to use a worker thread to gather my list and not block UI thread. here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SettingsActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, fontsName);       
    Spinner fontsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.settings_font_spinner);
    fontsSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);         

    // The thread to gather font names from /assets/fonts/
    thread =  new Thread(){  
        @Override  
        public void run(){  
            try {
                String[] fileList = getAssets().list("fonts");
                if (fileList != null)
                    for (int i=0; i<fileList.length; i++) {
                        adapter.add(fileList[i]);               
                    }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }                   
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }  
    };        
    thread.start(); 

}
```

but it causes an error and crash:

```
08-17 13:54:01.017: E/AndroidRuntime(17929): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Am I using runOnUiThread() correctly?! It's interesting that this code works perfectly when not using any thread, but it blocks UI (which is a pain).

any help on this please?

Comment: `adapter.add()` has to be done from UI thread as well

Comment: Think about using AsyncTask from Android ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html ). Also it is bad practice to consume an Exception without at least printing stack trace

Comment: @zapl thanks, it worked well after moving adapter.add(). but still I don't know why getAssets().list() takes 2 seconds for only 2 file names?!

Comment: @eftokay83 thanks, I'm very new to multi-Threading and AsyncTask. I just found this runOnUiThread very handy and simple to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As zapl mentioned, `adapter.add(Object)` has to be called from the UI thread.

You should use Android's [AsyncTask class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) rather than a Thread object. You could, for instance, load the data from file in AsyncTask's `doInBackground(Params...)` method and update the list view in the `onPostExecute(Result)` method.

Furthermore, you don't need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` explicitly; calls to `adapter.add(Object)` will notify the ListView that the adapter has changed.

Comment: and you dont need to call notifydatasetchanged, adapter.add will do it for you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
                for (int i=0; i<fileList.length; i++) {
                    adapter.add(fileList[i]);               
                }
```

Use the following instead (assuming `fontsName` is an `ArrayList<String>`):

```
                for (int i=0; i<fileList.length; i++) {
                    fontsName.add(fileList[i]);               
                }
```

The idea is to update the underlying data in the adapter (which is fine to be done on a different thread) and then notify the adapter about the change from the UI thread (using `notifyDataSetChanged()` as you have done).