# RunOnUIThread from CustomCursorAdapter

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

**What I Have**

I have a Custom Cursor Adapter from where I run a Thread to do some heave tasks.

**What I Want**

I want to update he UI upon completion of the thread, like showing a Toast.

**My Problem**

As I am inside the Custom Cursor Adapter, I am unable to get the Activity to use the `runOnUiThread` method like `getActivity().runOnUiThread()`. The Custom Cursor Adapter class is just a Java class and not an Activity or Fragment.

How can I get the `Activity` reference and execute the `runOnUiThread` method from my `CustomCursorAdapter`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to somehow pass a reference of your activity to your adapter. then through some casting or use of interfaces you can call on `((YourActivity)context).runOnUiThread()`

as for accessing the fragment manager, you need to do the same casting.

```
((YourActivity)context).getFragmentManager()
```

But be aware! this is not a good design pattern. if the `context` is no an activity, you will soon have to deal with lots of NPE exceptions and stuff. For example, `ApplicationContext` does not have `getFragmentManager` but when you do the casting above, your IDE will not notify you, you will find that out when you actually try it on emulator or device.

Using interfaces are a bit safer, at least you know that your activity has which interface implemented.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly. Can you tell me how can I have "getFragmentManager()" from it and do some fragment transactions?

Answer (score 15):

I know this is late, but I hope this approach helps other people.

This solution works if I have `Adapter (RecyclerView Adapter,Viewpager Adapter... etc)`, and in this adapter I'm working with `AsyncTask` and want to change some data by using that `AsyncTask`:

**1.runOnUiThread**

```java
((Activity)contextObject).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //change View Data
    }
});
```

**2. Handler**

The Handler class in Java and Kotlin lets you add a Runnable task to the message queue of the thread it is associated with. By creating a new Handler instance in your background thread, you can use it to post a Runnable task to be executed on the UI thread.

```java
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Code to run on the UI thread
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
  ((AppCompatActivity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {

                                            //context.refreshInbox();
                                        }
                                    });
```

Comment: Works for me in VeiwPagerAdapter, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best is to run your background jobs in an AsyncTask, and update your UI in the onPostExecute of the Asyntask as it runs on the UI thread.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12003493

Comment: Async task is deprecated now. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask